# Float property in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have two `p` tag and one (`id=floating`) is having css property `{float: right}`.

This affects the other `p` tag (`id=toCenter`) which have the style `{text-align: center}`.

ie. text alignment is only applicable to remaining area.

Even though this output is understandable, What should I do to have the `'toCenter'` `p` tag centering along the whole width.

I tried with `z-index`, but no result till now.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div>

      <p id='floating'>floating floating floating floating floating floating floating floating floating floating </p>

      <p id='toCenter'> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</p>

  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
#floating{
  background: red;  
  float: right;
}

#toCenter {
  text-align: center !important;
  background: yellow;
}
```

codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obJEap?editors=1100

Comment: can you please share a screenshot of your requirement

Comment: use `position:absolute; right:0;` instead of `float` - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxeYKW?editors=1100

Comment: just add `clear:right` to `#toCenter` element.

Comment: I recommend to read about block formatting context on W3C in order to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the floating as

```
#floating {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: While a code only answer solves the problem for the op, it isn't recommended as it provides no value for future visitors, a answer that only provides is quickly going to be flagged as "very low quality" and by the result of that it will be deleted quickly. [edit] your answer to include an explanation what the provided code does.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `toCenter` first before the `<p id="floating">` or you need to have `clear:right` on the toCenter style

Answer (score 0):

Put clear on second paragraph CSS :

```
#toCenter {
   text-align: center !important;
   background: yellow;
   clear:both;
}
```

Clearing float is required because  the non floating element follows the floated one and floated element shrinks to it's content's width.

Comment: But the 'center paragraph' goes to the next line, which I do not want.

Comment: That is what `<p>` tag is intended for. It puts the content in a new line always.

Comment: It was a demo man. Originally it is an image tag and a navigation bar(div)

Answer (score 0):

pls try the modified css from code pen

```css
div {
  background: green;
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

#floating{
  background: red;  
  float: right;
}

#toCenter {
  text-align: center !important;
  /*background: yellow;*/
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}



p {
  margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Nice. But the 'center paragraph' goes to the next line. @BenG comment worked fine for me.